# Stemming and Lemmatization on Array

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, nltk, stemming, lemmatization

I dont quite understand why I cannot Lemmatize or do Stemming. I tried converting the array to string, but I have no luck.

This is my code.

```
import bs4, re, string, nltk, numpy as np, pandas as pd
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen

news_url="https://news.google.com/news/rss"
Client=urlopen(news_url)
xml_page=Client.read()
Client.close()

soup_pg=soup(xml_page,"xml")
news_lst=soup_page.findAll("item")
limit=19
corpus = []
# Print news title, url and publish date
for index, news in enumerate(news_list):
        #print(news.title.text)
        #print(index+1)
        corpus.append(news.title.text)
        if index ==limit:
            break
#print(arrayList)
df = pd.DataFrame(corpus, columns=['News'])

wpt=nltk.WordPunctTokenizer()
stop_words=nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
def normalize_document (doc):
    #lowercase and remove special characters\whitespace
    doc=re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]', '', doc, re.I|re.A) #re.I ignore case sensitive, ASCII-only matching
    doc=doc.lower()
    doc=doc.strip()
    #tokenize document
    tokens=wpt.tokenize(doc)
    #filter stopwords out of document
    filtered_tokens=[token for token in tokens if token not in stop_words]
    #re-create documenr from filtered tokens
    doc=' '.join(filtered_tokens)
    return doc

normalize_corpus=np.vectorize(normalize_document)
norm_corpus=normalize_corpus(corpus)
norm_corpus
```

The error I get starts with the next lines I add

```
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(norm_corpus)
# Stemming
for i in range(len(norm_corpus)):
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(norm_corpus[i])
    words = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in words]
    norm_corpus[i] = ' '.join(words)
```

once I insert these lines then I get the following error:
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

I think if I solve the error with stemming it will be the same solution to my error with lemmatization.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `norm_corpus` is `numpy.ndarray`, i.e bytes. The `sent_tokenize` method expects a `string`, hence the error. You need to convert `norm_corpus` to a list of strings to get rid of this error.

What I don't understand is why would you vectorize the document before stemming? Is there a problem of doing it other way around, i.e first stemming and then vectorize. The error should be resolved then

Comment: Ive tried to make norm_corpus a string by using astype. However the datatype doesnt change.

Comment: Some of it. I changed it to add only 20 to a list so I could manipulate it.

Comment: Please share the link so that we can fully understand the code